# Manage "Authentication" tab for registered in AAD B2C application, using MS Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have registered Application in Azure AD B2C. Now I want to assign/change **Platform Configurations** in **Authentication** options using MS Graph SDK. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take adding Web platform with redirect uri as an example.

There is a property named `web` in an app registration.

We can update the app registration to add redirect uri (`https://localhost`) into this property.

Http example:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{application object id}

{
    "web": {
        "homePageUrl": null,
        "logoutUrl": null,
        "redirectUris": [
            "https://localhost"
        ],
        "implicitGrantSettings": {
            "enableAccessTokenIssuance": false,
            "enableIdTokenIssuance": false
        }
    }
}
```

Corresponding C# example:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var application = new Application
{
    Web = new WebApplication
    {
        HomePageUrl = null,
        LogoutUrl = null,
        RedirectUris = new List<String>()
        {
            "https://localhost"
        },
        ImplicitGrantSettings = new ImplicitGrantSettings
        {
            EnableAccessTokenIssuance = false,
            EnableIdTokenIssuance = false
        }
    }
};

await graphClient.Applications["{application object id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(application);
```

If you want to add Mobile and desktop applications platform, you can look into `publicClient` property, and `spa` property for Single-page application platform.

Comment: Do you know if and where it is documented? I can not find it but I need to handle Mobile, Spa and Desktop platforms as well.

Comment: @freak_geek See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example. Maybe this example is a little simple. You can call the endpoint in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) first and use the **Code snippets** feature to see the C# code. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwO2C.png.